# How can I Plot lines in different colors from a data in Graphics 3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, data

I want to plot all these different line in different colors to visualize them better. But all I get is the black color for all of them.

```
Graphics3D[Line[data], 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 20.0}, {0, 6}, {0, 400}},
  BoxRatios -> {0.7, 1, 1.5}, 
  Axes -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {r, logV, Vref}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 20],
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]]
```

[image: Here is the Output I get]

Comment: Obviously data consists  of sublists of points. With a colorlist  ( size= Length[data]) you could try `Graphics3D[Table[{color[[i]],data[[i]]},{i,1,Length[data]}]]`

Comment: try `Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Line@#}&/@data]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ListPointPlot3D` and post-process to change `Point`s to `Line`s:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data] /. Point -> Line
```

Alternatively, instead of a single `Line` primitive, have multiple `Line`s (one for each part of `data`) and  inject color directives before each line

```
 Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Line @ #} & /@ data]
```